# How Android handles the size of downloaded images?

Tags: android

I am working on an app that upon launched downloads an image from the web and displays it on the main activity.

My worry is the size that this image will have on devices with different screen densities.

**For example**: Suppose I am downloading an image which is 400x200 pixels. Will it be displayed 400x200 both on a Galaxy S (480x800 res) and on the Galaxy S3 (1280x720 res), or will it be resized to a larger size on the Galaxy S3?

Any tips on how this works and on how to be compatible with different screens when working with downloaded images?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're displaying the image in an ImageView, you really need to be concerned about a couple of things:

The layout_width/layout_height and the scaleType settings on your ImageView.

Android will take care of the upscaling/downscaling per these settings.

You can, if desired, adjust the width/height dynamically.  Using code similar to:

```
// banner image layout adjustment
LayoutParams lp = mImageView.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = mImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() ;
lp.height = mImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() ;
mImageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

but use caution to keep this view within some pre-defined bounds ... e.g. the device screen width/height.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the website does some fancy user-agent switching to provide different resolutions for the image requested, the image files should be the same coming down the wire. However, when displaying the image it will be resized to fit the screen (if scaling in an ImageView, for example). Due to different memory limitations across devices, if the image you retrieved is not downsampled you might run into out of memory errors when displaying it though (file size remains the same, it's just in-memory size that is the problem here).

Comment: I am more concerned with the displaying size, as images are small. I added an example to the question to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the ImageView layout and attributes more than on the source image, in that case.